# Sendmail. Store all email received creating unique single file

Tags: linux, email, sendmail

i'm actually facing a problem due integration with a custom applicance of a customer.

Sendmail is really easy to configure and understand but what i need is quite complicated to realize.

The appliance would read the email received, process them and store some data in his db. To do this customer asked me if it is possible that sendmail, when receives an email, does not happend the email in a single file under the user profile, but stores them in a specidified path with a a email file for every email processed.

It is possible to do it or there's any genial idea to trick it and let it work?

Thank you

S.

Comment: What is the difference between this problem and the [question you asked earlier](https://serverfault.com/q/877927)?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the email is being stored in Mbox format which is just a single file with every email one after the other. This format is rarely used these days as in modern usage it tends to grow pretty quickly and become cumbersome.

The most simple thing would be to configure Sendmail to use Procmail for local delivery, and configure Procmail to store messages in Maildir format.

The exact process will depend on the OS but it should just be a case of installing Procmail, then

1) Configure Sendmail to use Procmail, which is most cases just means adding the following lines to the `.mc` configuration file and rebuilding the config.

```
FEATURE(local_procmail)
MAILER(procmail)
```

2) Create or update the `procmailrc` configuration file to store messages in Maildir format. (Signified by a `/` on the end of the storage path)

```
DEFAULT=$HOME/mail/
```

The `mail` directory will likely need to exist and have `cur`, `new` and `tmp` subfolders. These should be owned by the user and have mode 700 permissions.

Looking for information on Sendmail/Procmail/Maildir for your OS may help you find some guides or documentation.

Answer (score 1):

`sendmail` uses another program(s) to deliver messages to local recipients.
On Linux-es it is usually `procmail`.  Procmail can deliver messages to [maildir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maildir) or [mh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MH_Message_Handling_System) folder. Both seems to be roughly what you want.

As root  use the command below to check which program is used by sendmail as local mailer:
`echo '=M' | sendmail -bt | grep local`

**OR**
convince customer to use [IMAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imap) or [POP3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pop3) for accessing the mailbox. UID (Unique identifier) may deliver what the customer wants in more portable way.

Answer (score 0):

Letting the application read files from a pick-up location is probably a bad design idea. Writing e-mail messages is not an atomic operation and you don't want the application to pick up incomplete messages.

(The Maildir format prevents this by writing incoming messages to a `tmp/` directory, that is not exposed to mail clients. Only once the message file has been successfully committed to disk will the message file be renamed/moved  to the `new/` directory, as that is an atomic operation.)

The generic solution for applications to ingest e-mail is, as [@AnFi already suggested](https://serverfault.com/a/878668/37681), to get the application to behave as a mail client and let it poll an IMAP/POP3 mailbox and skip/delete messages that have been processed successfully.

Similarly generic is to have the application ingest e-mail messages from STDIN.

- You can then still create a wrapper that will poll a mailbox so you won't have to install anything on your mailserver :)
  Use your favourite scripting language to create such a wrapper or leverage a existing tool such as : [`fetchmail <other-options> --mda /path/to/application`](http://www.fetchmail.info/)
- Alternatively if you do want to install the application on the mail server: the <kbd>|</kbd> allows you to forward messages directly to any application from either:
  A `~/.forward` file that contains a line `"|/path/to/application"`
  The [`/etc/aliases`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/aliases.sendmail) file with an entry `mailboxname: "|/path/to/application"`

For sendmail the latter often requires that you configure the sendmail restricted shell ([smrsh](https://linux.die.net/man/8/smrsh)) by copying /path/to/application to /etc/smrsh